# Using on('click') when I could also use .click()

Tags: jquery, onclick

I know that `.click(function())` doesn't work on dynamic objects, but `.on('click', function())` does, given the circumstance.

Is there any downside to using `.on('click')` all of the time?

I've become accustom to using `.on` to handle all of my events, regardless of whether it's dynamic or not.

Comment: This is not event delegation. These are just 2 different ways of binding events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just two different ways of adding an event handler,

See here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-versus-click/2

They are almost identical, but `.on('click', function()` seems to be faster by the smallest amount.

**.click(function()**

```
143,775
±5.23%
fastest
```

vs

**.on('click', function()**

```
148,059
±5.66%
fastest
```

Comment: You're reading the results incorrectly, `.on('click', function() {})` is the faster of the two. That makes sense, considering `.click()` calls `.on('click')` internally, as far as I recall.